# div width autoadjust to its content

Tags: css, html

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/domoindal/fkcQK/

What i need is that the border fit its content in the menu bar, so if there are three tags, the width of such div should fit to the sum of that three tags widths. I do not want the border around the tags get the max width.

Latter, what i want to get is creating a shadow around the resulting irregular shape, not a box.

Is there any possibility of doing it as i want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use float

http://jsfiddle.net/fkcQK/1/

Comment: Thanks, one more thing... in the new code: http://jsfiddle.net/domoindal/fkcQK/3/  how could i avoid the shadow just below the menu? i would like a surrounded shadow uniform.

Comment: I think i did not express well, i meant the shadow that appear between the bottom border of the menu and the upper border of the body should not appear.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the width: auto bits and add a display: inline-block to your menu div:-

http://jsfiddle.net/fkcQK/2/

Answer (score 1):

Your `width: auto;` properties won't help because `<div>` is a block element and automatically fills the width of its parent. In the browser's built-in stylesheet there is a definition that says `div { width: auto; display: block; }` your CSS there doesn't change anything.

What you want is done in this jsFiddle I found just now: http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/seB5F/

It makes the parent `position: absolute;` without defining any location coordinates, so the element's box fits its content (as it has no parent to fill into), however this does remove the element from the document's flow so you'll need to assign a margin or padding to nearby elements to mask that fact.

HTH.

A small note: in future, consider making navigation menus (which conceptually are lists) `<ul>` elements instead of the generic `<div>`.